# cannot convert clob to string

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, clob

I am trying to convert my clob object to string to display that on my JSTL page for that I am writting the following code

```
public String convertClobToString(Clob clob){
     String toRet="";
     if(clob!=null)
     {
         try
         {
             long length=clob.length();
             toRet=clob.getSubString(1, (int)length);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
             TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     return toRet;
 }
```

but while counting the length using "long length = clob.length()" its throwing following  exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Must be logged on to server

at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.check_error(DBError.java:1160)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.assertLoggedIn(TTC7Protocol.java:2196)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.lobLength(TTC7Protocol.java:2698)
at oracle.sql.LobDBAccessImpl.length(LobDBAccessImpl.java:468)
at oracle.sql.CLOB.length(CLOB.java:214)
at org.hibernate.lob.SerializableClob.length(SerializableClob.java:33)
at com.starcj.cmt.application.dao.ApplicationDaoImpl.convertClobToString(ApplicationDaoImpl.java:110)
at com.starcj.cmt.termsandcondmgmt.dao.TermsAndCondDaoImpl.getAllActiveTermsandcond(TermsAndCondDaoImpl.java:91)
at com.starcj.cmt.termsandcondmgmt.service.TermsAndCondServiceImpl.getAllActiveTermsAndCond(TermsAndCondServiceImpl.java:43)
at com.starcj.cmt.termsandcondmgmt.controller.TermsAndCondListingCMTController.handleRequest(TermsAndCondListingCMTController.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Exceptoin isMust be logged on to server

but I am getting the clob object from database

Comment: Suffering from the same problem.Still not understand how it happens. Please tell me how you fixed it?

Answer (score 5):

In your hibernate entity (which we can't see) declare the property to be of type `String` and annotate it with `@Lob` (again, I don't know whether you are using annotations or XML), and it will work without the need for any manual conversion.

This happens because at the time you are trying to parse the entity, the session and the underlying connection are closed, so you can't stream the value of the CLOB from the database.

An alternative for the above solution might be to use an [OpenSessionInView](https://www.hibernate.org/43.html) Filter. It will let you have the session (and the underlying database connection) open while rendering the view (i.e. your jsps)

Answer (score 2):

Where are you getting the CLOB from? Is the Connection that created it still open?
The error message seems to indicate the database connection has been closed in the meantime.
If you are using Hibernate, is the Hibernate Session still open?

Comment: can you edit your stack trace and code properly? That's done by putting four spaces before each line.

Comment: I am using oracle 9.0 and using hibernate and connection is not closed in meantime connection is still open

Comment: "connection is not closed". Can you verify that? Maybe something like `hibernateSession.createSQLQuery("select * from dual").executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 1):

`Clob resume = Hibernate.createClob ( "This is Clob");`