# How to convert a CLOB data type to a String in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle10g, clob

In hibernate (3.2.1.GA), I use the following method to insert CLOB type data into Oracle (10g) database.

```
Hibernate.createClob(parameters.get("txtCatImage"));
```

`parameters` is a `Map` where all the request parameters have been stored. While retrieving the `Clob` data type from the database directly something like this `entityObj.getCatImage()` would not work.

Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644559/1391249) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2278445/1391249) questions but couldn't find the way.

The following is the entity that uses a `Clob` type property.

```
public class Category  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long catId; // Primary key.
    private Clob catImage; // CLOB type field.
    // Other fields.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Category() {}

    // Overloaded constructs + getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

<sub>The `Clob` field in the database just stores an image file name, in this case.</sub>

Comment: Define 'would not work.' Are you getting an error or is it returning `null`?

Comment: @Dev - It doesn't give any error. It just displays an object reference something like this `org.hibernate.lob.SerializableClob@1e2ad75` with either `obj.getCatImage().toString()` or `obj.getCatImage()` instead of showing the actual contents which is an image file name in the Oracle database. The actual SQL on the Oracle prompt like `SELECT * FROM category` however shows the actaul contents on the Oracle terminal directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either call [`Clob.getSubString(long, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getSubString%28long,%20int%29) with appropriate arguments to get the desired `String` or read the Clob as an InputStream or Reader using [`Clob.getAsciiStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getAsciiStream%28%29) or [`Clob.getCharacterStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getCharacterStream%28%29).

If the Clob has fewer than 2147483647 (a.k.a. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) characters you can do this

```
Clob clob = ... //Your clob
String clobString = clob.getSubString(0, clob.length());
```

Comment: `getSubString()`: The first character is at position 1, not 0, strangely, but this is what JavaDoc says

Comment: it's possible that in an early version the position began from 0. Also, both parameter must be int (clob.length() returns long so you need to convert that too).

Answer (score 3):

The solution from Dev (see above) to use "Clob.getSubString(long, int)" will be cost a lot of memory.
I prefer the following solution.

```
private static String getAsString(Clob clob) {
    Reader reader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        reader = clob.getCharacterStream();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        return IOUtils.toString(bufferedReader);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while reading String from CLOB", e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(catImage.getAsciiStream())).readLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, clob.getSubString(0, clob.length()) consumes memory and bad performance too.
I had the same issue, where i am fetching a field of huge length varchar2(2000-4000 ) data from DB. The performance was slowing down just because of this varchar field to 1 min 20 secs. Fetching from Database to Entity classs was fast, but copying from  Entity to SO object(or POJO) was taking huge time.

I am using JPA for DB data fetching. 
Entity field I kept as String.
In SO Object(POJO) that field type I set as CLOB datatype.

After fetching data from DB, the data is available in Entity object.
To copy to SO object(CLOB type),

```
SOobject.setLongStringField( new SerialClob(entityString.toCharArray()));//Converting String to CLOB
```

And at UI level, my SOobject, instead of normal getter setter method , i used as below (Alex's code)

```
public String getLongStringField() {
         Reader reader = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                reader = longStringField.getCharacterStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                return IOUtils.toString(bufferedReader);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                throw new RuntimeException("Error while reading String from CLOB", e);
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
            }
    }

    public void setLongStringField(Clob longStringField) {
        this.longStringField= longStringField;
    }
```

hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to read everything:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clob.getAsciiStream())).lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```